# Adding google analytics ecommerce tracking to woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, woocommerce, e-commerce

I need to add the google analytics ecommerce tracking to a wordpress site with woocommerce.

I understand I need to add the code for tracking and on this page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce it says I need to add some codes to a thank you page.

I've tried adding these codes via a
`add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_tracking' );` 
but in most cases I get some php error or it doesn't work.

Also, I've tried google ecommerce integration [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-google-analytics-integration/) but it didn't work.

What part of the GA ecommerce tracking code do I need to add and where to be able to track conversions on google analytics ?

Answer (score 0):

First You need to add analytics tracking code in the footer. You can do that like this:

```
<?php
function your_function() {
   echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );
?>
```

Then you need to add conversion tracking code, You can do that by editing your theme's thankyou.php page

Comment: Thanks. From the google docs link could you tell me which part of code to take and where to place. I've tried with your function and it's still not picking it up. I'm using tag asistant plugin to test conversion hits.